# Uma das mensagens após a edição está em inglês

Tags: bug, internacionalização

Após realizar uma edição de uma pergunta, apareceram as seguintes mensagens:

```
Obrigado por sua edição!
This edit will be visible only to you until it is peer reviewed.
```

A segunda delas está em inglês, mas deveria estar em português.